# Flask - cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, flask

It's been a long time since I have written any Python and I'm trying to remember how to lay out a best flask app

I have a app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
import os
from blueprints.users import users_blueprint
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

# Blueprints
app.register_blueprint(users_blueprint)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
@jwt_required()
def index():
    return jsonify(message="Hello Flask!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

Then I created a Users Model:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(16))
    last_name = Column(String(16))
    phone = Column(String(16))
    email = Column(String(32), unique=True)
    password = Column(String(128))

@app.cli.command("db_create")
def db_create():
    db.create_all()
    print("Database created")


@app.cli.command("db_drop")
def db_drop():
    db.drop_all()
    print("Database dropped")


@app.cli.command("db_seed")
def db_seed():
    test_user = User(
        first_name="Graham",
        last_name="Graham",
        phone="phone",
        email="graham@email.com",
        password=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(["password"]).decode(
            "utf-8"
        ),
    )
    db.session.add(test_user)
    db.session.commit()
    print("Database seeded")



# DB Schemas
class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "phone", "password")


# Marsh mellow db adds
user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)
```

and then I have a User blueprint:

```py
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
from app import app
from models.users import User, db
users_blueprint = Blueprint('users_blueprint', __name__)

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)


@users_blueprint.route("/register", methods=["POST"])
def register():
    email = request.json["email"]
    test = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if test:
        return jsonify(message="That email already exists"), 409
    else:
        first_name = request.json["first_name"]
        last_name = request.json["last_name"]
        email = request.json["email"]
        phone = request.json["phone"]
        password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.json["password"]).decode(
            "utf-8"
        )

        user = User(
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            email=email,
            phone=phone,
            password=password,
        )
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return jsonify(message="User created successfully"), 201


@users_blueprint.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
        if request.is_json:
            email = request.json["email"]
            password = request.json["password"]
        else:
            email = request.form["email"]
            password = request.form["password"]

        test = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        
        if test:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(test.password, password):
                access_token = create_access_token(identity=email)
                return jsonify(message="Login Successful", access_token=access_token)
        else:
            return jsonify("Bad email or password"), 401
```

I'm trying to have it import the app as and where needed but get the error

```
Flask cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I feel I might be missing a step to get this to work or maybe Im over doing it with the app import.